# Player Notification Manager

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-media3

I use jetpack compose media3 and I heve this bug
I need help to fix it

```
setChannelNameResourceId(R.string.notification_channel)
setChannelDescriptionResourceId(R.string.notification_channel_description)
```

[api33 media3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L78XO.png)

```
notification_channel not found
```

```
notification_channel_description not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to set the channel name and description for a notification in your Android app, but the resource IDs for those strings are not being found. This can happen if the string resources have not been properly added to your app's `strings.xml` file.

Make sure that the `notification_channel` and `notification_channel_description` strings are added to `strings.xml` file, using the correct syntax:

```
<resources>
    <string name="notification_channel">My Channel</string>
    <string name="notification_channel_description">My description</string>
    ...
</resources>
```

Comment: Thank you so much ,
I searched for hours but no result, when I started to use ( Jetpack Compose ) I completely forgot something called ( xml ), you saved me. really thank you✨